# How to get user information in ASP.NET Core 3.1 from Azure AD B2C user store?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

The ASP.NET Core 3.1 app has been created using the Visual Studio new project wizard. Mostly default options were used, however authentication was configured to use individual user accounts stored in Azure AD B2C.

The web application is scaffolded by Visual Studio, compiles, and runs just fine. And when logging in, the current user name is printed in the header using `@User.Identity.Name`.

After fiddling around with `@User.Identity.Name`, it is not clear how to access the rest of the user information or "claims" stored in AAD B2C.

What is the correct/suggested way to access user information stored in AAD B2C within an MVC controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `UserManager` in your Classes using Dependency Injection. An example is given below:

```
using ContactManager.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace ContactManager.Pages.Contacts
{
    public class DI_BasePageModel : PageModel
    {
        protected ApplicationDbContext Context { get; }
        protected IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService { get; }
        protected UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; }

        public DI_BasePageModel(
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            IAuthorizationService authorizationService,
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager) : base()
        {
            Context = context;
            UserManager = userManager;
            AuthorizationService = authorizationService;
        } 
    }
}
```

*And, you can use `FindByNameAsync` or `FindByIdAsync` to fetch the user.*

You can follow [this excellent material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1) **on .NET Core 3.1 Identity**.